# Javascript/Jquery: replace string pattern with link

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a table on a page, where there are text entries, and have one or more "hashtags", which I want to identify via JavaScript/JQuery and replace them with a link.

Currently I am using the following regex selector for hashtags: `/#([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/g`

I have been experimenting with `replaceWith` and `replace` methods of JQuery, but I couldn't achieve the desired result yet.

Example entries on the page:

```
<td class="entry">Had meeting with client #Project1</td>
```

This is my desired output (after manipulating via JavaScript/JQuery):

```
`<td class="entry">Had meeting with client <a href="search.php?`query=#Project1">#Project1</a></td>
```

Does someone help out with a function/for this?  As my code is not close to working I am I choosing not to post the code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this solution will help ?

```js
document.querySelectorAll("table td.entry").forEach((el) => {
  el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML.replace(/#([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/g, '<a href="search.php?`query=#$1">#$1</a>')
})
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <td class="entry">Had meeting with client #Project1</td>
    <td class="entry">Had meeting with client #Project2</td>
    <td class="entry">Had meeting with client #Project3</td>
    <td class="entry">Had meeting with client #Project4</td>
    <td class="entry">Had meeting with client #Project5</td>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: thank you, I missed that I couldn't just select the class when using a table.  Your answer brought me on the right track!

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this using JavaScript:

```js
const entries = document.querySelectorAll(".entry");

entries.forEach((entry) => {
  entry.innerText.match(/#([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/g).forEach((hash) => {
    entry.innerHTML = entry.innerHTML.replace(
      hash,
      `<a href="search.php?query=${hash}">${hash}</a>`
    );
  });
});
```

```html
<p class="entry">Had meeting with client #Project1</p>
<p class="entry">Had meeting with client #Project2 & #Project3</p>
```

Comment: thank you! I used your javascript and the correct selector for tables from Oleg Barabanov

Answer (score 0):

try it:

```
const str= '<td class="entry">Had meeting with client #Project1</td>';

const match = str.match(/#([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/g);

var result = str.replace(match[0],`<a href="search.php?query=${match[0]}">${match[0]}</a>`);
```